# convert IP address (local network) to UNC path

Tags: c++, winapi, network-programming

Windows UNC paths usually are in the form `\\computerName\share\blah`, however instead of the computer name there could be the equivalent IP address eg `\\127.0.0.1\share`.

How can one get the real computer name behind this IP address using windows API? I found a solution using winsock ([`gethostbyaddr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738521%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) but I would wish to avoid this dependency if possible. I have tried `NetShareEnum` and `DnsHostnameToComputerName` without any luck

Comment: Have you looked at the [`DnsQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682016.aspx) function? Although I don't really understand why you're trying to avoid a dependency on WinSock. You're going to have to do a reverse DNS lookup in order to accomplish this. Sockets seems like the logical approach to me.

Comment: This IP lookup function is not an essential part of my program (which has to run in all win32 version) so I am trying to avoid everything that introduces extra dependencies. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Winsock exists on all Win32 OSs. Why not just use it as an IP address in the path? It will still work.